# Saving Instance of Fragment's ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a Main Activity which contains two Fragments (Frag A and Frag B).
Only one Fragment is to be shown at a time.
Both Fragments are contain a ListView (Common for both Frag A and Frag B).

**1.When Activity is created Frag A loads all its values through an AsyncTask**

**2.When I push a button I switch to Frag B which does the same process**

**3.Again on push of a button I Switch to Frag A and the AsyncTask is called again**

> I don't want to carry out the third step .Instead I just want to save the instance of Frag A. So the contents are not loaded again.How can I do it?

I know i will have to stop calling AsyncTask again which will be taken care of. Any help with saving of Instance State is much appreciated.

```
public class DepositFragement extends Fragment {
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String TAG="DEPOSITS FRAGMENT";
PrefManager pref;
ListView depList;
ListView depoList;
Boolean isFirstTime=true;
Parcelable depoListInstance;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.deposits_fragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("Depo Instance", depoList.onSaveInstanceState());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        depoListInstance = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Depo Instance");
        depoList.onRestoreInstanceState(depoListInstance);
    }



    depoList=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvDepositList);

    if(isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        if(isFirstTime) {
            new LoadDeposits().execute();
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
    }

}





}
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant piece of code to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Assuming you are doing a fragment replace, fragment data can be loaded everytime fresh from local cache. The point is are you caching the list values anywhere? If not, probably you might want to look into caching it and then using that value to load your list on FragA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a flag on the fragment - like `isLoaded` that is set to `true` when the AsyncTask returns with the data.

Then, in the `onCreate` method of the fragment, you can use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

So that the data is preserved when the fragment is paused.

In the post execute callback of your async task, set a field to the data returned.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> result) {
    DepositFragement.this.dataResult = result;
    refreshAdapter();
}
```

In the onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(this.dataResult != null) {
        refreshAdapter();
    }
}

void refreshAdapter() {
    adapter.data = dataResult;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Do i have to save Instance state in onPause() method?

Comment: Nope, just set the setRetainInstance and it'll do everything for you. Plus, saving instance state on the `onPause()` method of a fragment can be unreliable.

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } I did this but the listview is empty

Comment: You haven't provided any code, but in the onResume of the fragment, you may need to just set the list view adapter's data to the saved data field and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I am using SimpleAdapter. Doesn't support adapter.data method @jyanks

Comment: You just need to re-initialize the adapter then with the new data, then reattach it to the list view.

Comment: Oh god why....This simple thing worked after going through all the possible solutions. Just reinitialized the adapter and did listView.setAdapter(adapter) in onResume() when isLoaded variable is false. Thanx @jyanks

Answer (score -1):

For each fragment you can override the onSaveInstanceState method and save whatever you want in there.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Save the fragment's state here
}
```

also you should retrieve it by overriding onActivityCreated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this.But I am not really sure how to save instance of a listview inside a fragment and how to retain it. Can u help me with that? @Shrey

Comment: you can save the list of elements that you want to put in the listView and recreate its adapter when the activity is created.

So onSaveInstanceState you would outState.putStringArray(listArray)
and onActivityCreated you could retrieve that list and update the adapter for the listView and call notifyDataSetChanged()